# Having issues with Jmeter Login Test keep on failing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am trying to learn the Jmeter and performing simple login test for a test website. but I am keep on getting following error,

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-05 18:56:28 NZST
Load time: 40
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 40
Size in bytes: 237
Sent bytes:757
Headers size in bytes: 237
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized
```

### Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2019 06:56:28 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.skillswap.pro


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, but you could try to investigate by **displaying the HTML of the response** to see what you get. You can find this feature in the **View Results tree** component

[image]

Also, sometimes there are **tokens** or other variables that are shared or incremented between your pages. In such case, you have to store them in a variable and give it back at each HTTP request.

[image]

To retrieve a token for example, you can use a **Regular expression extractor**, just look how it looks in your html. Here for example, it was in an hidden input tag.

[image]

I hope this puts you on the track to find the solution !

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helps a lot.